# I wrote a event manager code in Javascript. :( but something went wrong

Tags: javascript

I wrote a event manager code in Javascript. :( but something went wrong. The code is not working.anyone please help me

**CODE**

```
var plan = prompt("Hello , Made a week plan. Type the week name to add a event");
var week = [saturday, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thrusday, friday];
var saturday = '';



if (plan == saturday) {
    var saturday = prompt("What will you do in saturday?");
}

var getknow = prompt("Do you want to cheack the schedule? Type the week name");
if (getknow == saturday) {
    alert(saturday);
}
```

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: [saturday, sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thrusday, friday]; These are variables, use quotes for strings: "saturday", "sunday", etc...

Comment: Also, why are you decalring the `week` array if you're not even using it?

Comment: You are comparing plan with empty variable saturday.

Comment: i dont know what is debugging i am new to programming @Jan Dvorak

Comment: @PramitoRahman open the javascript console, please. In chrome or firefox, CTRL+SHIFT+J

Comment: @PramitoRahman you have to know the basics first, Just refer a book like `Javascript - the missing manual` to get a grip over Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want. :)

```
var plan=prompt("Hello , Made a week plan. Type the week name to add a event");
var week = ['saturday' , "sunday" , "monday" , "tuesday" , "wednesday" , "thrusday" , "friday"];
//            var saturday = '';

        if( plan == "saturday" ) {

            var saturday=prompt("What will you do in saturday?");
        }

        var getknow=prompt("Do you want to cheack the schedule? Type the week name");

        if ( getknow == saturday ) {

            alert(saturday);

        }
```

Comment: variable `saturday` will be out of scope, if, plan == "saturday" condition fails.

Comment: I just made his code working now all other condition checks he should check .